# Get the MAC addres in ASP.NET MVC, limit access to registered equipment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I require to create a site in ASP.NET MVC C # that allows me to limit access to a computer registered user, what is the best way, get the MAC address? How?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is an English-only site.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the client Mac address, since there is no direct link between the client and the web site. The Mac address is found on the client's ethernet physical layer, and you do not have direct access to their hardware configuration. I think the best you can get is get the client IP address by:

```
String clientIpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but even that is "iffy" since it is behind the client's ISP's gateway and the actual computer would probably be connected behind a router or firewall.

If the client is a registered user, you would probably want to restrict access based on their login record that you define.

Answer (score 0):

MAC Address is only available at a much lower level in the networking stack. A MAC address is used at the Data Link Layer in the OSI networking model. It is only available for direct connections (meaning, your PC knows the MAC of your router and your router knows the MAC of your PC and of your ISP's router). When we communicate over the Internet, we're communicating with IP addresses which are at a much higher level in the OSI stack. When you connect to say Google.com, the direct connection to Google doesn't happen from your PC to Google.com. There are potentially dozens of hops in between. The MAC address Google sees is the MAC address of the router that actually makes the physical connection to their server, not yours. That way it can send a message back to that MAC. That MAC then forwards to the MAC of the next closest hop, all the way back until it finally has your ISP talking to the MAC of your modem, which talks to the MAC of your router, then to the MAC of your PC.

Even if it was possible over the Internet (which it definitely isn't) it's a terrible idea. Every router I've seen in the last 20 years has a feature called MAC spoofing. You can set your MAC address to anything you want which makes it a poor security mechanism. If you want to restrict access to your website, either use usernames and passwords or certificates. You could use IP addresses as someone else suggested, but depending on your use case, remember most users on the Internet have dynamic IP addresses so you can't be guaranteed they'll always have the same IP every time they connect to your server.